# Error querying DTO navigation properties with "any"

Tags: vb.net, breeze

In my `BreezeController` I have a method that returns a DTO with two properties.  One property is a navigation property to one of my entities, and the other a boolean:

```vb
Public Function ProjectList() As IQueryable
    Return From p In _contextProvider.Context.Projects
           Where Not p.IsDeleted
           Select New ProjectListItem() With {
               .Project = p,
               .HasTasks = (From t In _contextProvider.Context.ProjectTasks Where t.ProjectID = p.ID).Any()
           }
End Function

Public Class ProjectListItem
    Public Property Project As Project
    Public Property HasTasks As Boolean
End Class
```

Simple queries against this method work fine, but my `Project` class has a collection of project managers, and using an "any" query against this collection is failing in the Breeze client code, before sending the query to the server, with the following error message:

```
Exception was thrown at line 10698, column 13 in http://localhost:2780/myapp/Scripts/breeze.debug.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'isAnonymous' of undefined or null reference
```

This is in the `proto._validate` method of `FnNode`, where `entityType` is null.

My query (I'm trying to find all projects for a specific project manager) is built up in pieces, but the relevant parts are:

```
var p = breeze.Predicate.create("ProjectManagerID", op.Equals, id);
var predicate = breeze.Predicate.create("Project.ProjectManagers", "any", p);

// code common to all queries...
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("ProjectList");
query = query.where(predicate);
query = query.select("Project.Prop1,Project.Prop2,Project.etc,HasTasks");
return query.using(this.manager).execute();
```

I create other predicates and run them through the same common logic and they work fine, so it seems to be limited to "any" queries, e.g. this one works...

```
predicate = breeze.Predicate.create("Project.ClientNumber", op.Contains, search)
    .or("Project.ClientName", op.Contains, search)
    .or("Project.Notes", op.Contains, search);
```

I am still using Breeze 1.4.16 (WebAPI v1, .NET 4.0), but have tried updating the Breeze.Client package to 1.5.1, which makes no difference.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

If I manually build the OData query I am looking for, then I get the results that I want, e.g.

```
http://localhost:1234/myApp/breeze/myController/ProjectList?$filter=Project/ProjectManagers/any(p:p/ProjectManagerID eq 234)&$select=Project/Prop1,Project/Prop2,HasTasks
```